# Is it possible to create a custom version of jbutton to restrict access to certain methods?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to create a custom version of a swing component, say jbutton, that restricts access to certain methods of jbutton?

I want to have a jbutton (or various swing elements) where I define certain elements that can't be changed and certain that can. Using jbutton as an example, I'd like to allow a user of the class to add a text, or image to the button, set it enabled or disabled or set the size etc, but I want to define the look of the button and not have that modified.

If I extend jbutton using my custom class, I can only override each method I don't want modified with an unsupported exception. If I extend J component, I will have to rewrite basically all of jbutton. Is there a better way?

I'm asking because we are making a set of custom J components that clients can use to build hmi screens. We want to limit elements based on our look and feel and hmi standards.

Comment: I dont know of a better way than extending and throwing an exception for the methods you dont want them to use. I wish I could be more helpful. Is there a reason for trying to block the look and feel settings? If someone truly wanted to muck with the look, reflection could most likely still allow them to change it even if you do throw an exception?

Comment: "I don't want modified with an unsupported exception" how about setting a default value instead of throwing an exception ? It you use such workaround it should be well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend a `JPanel` or wrap your button (or even both of them).

First variant

```
public class MyButton extends JPanel {
    private JButton button = new JButton();
    public MyButton() {
        init();
    }
    // probably some another constructors.
    private void init() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout()); // button take the entire place of the panel
        add(button);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        button.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Second variant:

```
public class MyButton {
    private JButton button = new JButton();
    public MyButton() {
    }
    // probably some another constructors.

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return button;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        button.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Both of these variants allow you to hide the restricted functionality without to reimplement JButton or throw exceptions in overriden methods. You can also combine these two variants or each of these variants with throwing exception for restricted methods (it could be interesting, because some experienced developers can access `JButton` object, by casting to `JButton` the result of the method `getComponent()`).